# Cordova SMS sending on Mashmallow: not asking for permissions any more

Tags: android, cordova, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I use the cordova 6.4 with that plugin:

> cordova-plugin-sms 1.0.5 "SMS"

When I do install it, on **Android 4.3** it **asks for sms sending permissions** and **works great**.

On Marshmallow however, the APK installs WITHOUT asking any permissions (and of course cannot send SMS until I go manually to application, parameters and allow manually SMS sending)

In my /plateforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml I have that

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.proxymis.sendSMS" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
</manifest>
```

**Question: How to set permissions or config so I can send SMS with Marshmallow ?**

Answer (score 0):

Below Android 6.0, you ask for them in the manifest (like you did), and you always have access to them.

On Android 6.0 or higher, permissions have to be asked for at runtime.

Google "Android runtime permissions" and you will find loads and loads of guides and posts about it.

I've never worked with Cordova before, so i don't know how that will work, i've only worked with native Android applications. But my best guess is that there is a plugin that can help you.

Comment: ok, what if I use: 
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

will that work on android6 ?